# Change values in form depending on a single element

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a form, wich uses a query as source:

```
SELECT 
    [UserName], 
    [WBS_Id], 
    [Koptekst] 
FROM 
    tbl_New_WPE_User 
WHERE 
    [UserName] = funcActiveUser();
```

On the form I currently have 2 elements (probably more later)

[image: Form_WPE]

In the dropdown menu, I want the form to show all `WBS_id`'s that are assigned to the current user.

However, when i select the dropdown list setting and input  `WBS_Id` as control source, it only shows 1 WBS Id.

what I would like to accomplish, is seeing the data in the comment field (the large box to the right) change when I change the WBS id in the listbox

---

Edit: If I run the query, this is the outcome:

[image: query table]

Comment: Have you checked that running the SQL statement returns the right result (without the GUI)?

Comment: Yep, running the query as a single query gives me a table with all the values I would like to see. I will update my question with the table that is returned